# Using {[#custom}} contents {{/custom}} in Meteor

Tags: templates, meteor

I've just begun using the [`templates:tabs` package](https://atmospherejs.com/templates/tabs) for Meteor. By default, this generates a custom template that is inserted as `{{#basicTabs tabs=tabs}}`.

I have made a simple app to understand how this kind of custom template works, and in particular to understand how this is different from using {{> custom}}

HTML:

```
<body>
  {{> parent1}}
  {{> parent2}}
</body>

<template name="parent1">
  <h1>Parent 1</h1>
  {{> child}}
</template>

<template name="parent2">
  <h1>Parent 2</h1>
  {{#child}}
    <h2>Stuff inside "child" tag</h2>
  {{/child}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  <button type="button">Child button</button>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.child.events({
    'click button': function (event, template) {
       console.log("child", event, template)
    }
  });
  Template.parent1.events({
    'click button': function (event, template) {
      console.log("parent1", event, template)
    }
  });
  Template.parent2.events({
    'click button': function (event, template) {
      console.log("parent2", event, template)
    }
  });
}
```

I don't see any of the `Stuff inside the "child" tag` appearing. When I click on a button, I can see in the browser console that both the parent and the child templates can react to the input, but this happens in both cases.

How should I be using the `{{#custom}} ... {{/custom}}` syntax?

---

EDIT

Here are updated files that show how the {{#child}} block works, in connection with `events` and `helpers`:

```
<body>
  {{> parent1}}
  {{> parent2}}
</body>

<template name="parent1">
  <h1>Parent 1</h1>
  {{> child}}
</template>

<template name="parent2">
  <h1>Parent 2</h1>
  {{#child}}
    <h2>Stuff inside "child" tag</h2>
  {{else}}
    <h3>Other stuff</h3>
  {{/child}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  {{extras}}
  {{> Template.contentBlock}}
  {{> Template.elseBlock}}
  <button type="button">Child button</button>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.child.events({
    'click button': function (event, template) {
       console.log("child", event, template)
    }
  });
  Template.parent1.events({
    'click button': function (event, template) {
      console.log("parent1", event, template)
    }
  });
  Template.parent2.events({
    'click button': function (event, template) {
      console.log("parent2", event, template)
    }
  });

  Template.child.helpers({
    extras: function () {
      return "Child extras"
    }
  })
  Template.parent1.helpers({
    extras: function () {
      return "Parent 1 extras"
    }
  })
  Template.parent2.helpers({
    extras: function () {
      return "Parent 2 extras"
    }
  })
}
```

Output with Meteor 1.2.0.2:

> **Parent 1**
>
> Child extras  [Child button]
>
> **Parent 2**
>
> Child extras
>
> *Stuff inside "child" tag*
>
> *Other stuff*
>
> [Child button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only thing you're lacking here is `Template.contentBlock`, i.e.

```
<template name="child">
  <button type="button">Child button</button>
  {{> Template.contentBlock}}
</template>
```

You can think of it as a helper capable of rendering whatever the user of your `child` template puts within the `{{#child}}..{{/child}}` block.

Back to your question, the main difference between `{{> child}}` and `{{#child}}` is that the former has `Template.contentBlock` equal to `null`. For your information, there is also another helper `Template.elseContentBlock` which represents the part of markup placed after the `{{else}}` "tag", e.g.

```
{{#child}}
   this content goes to Template.contentBlock
{{else}}
   this content goes to Template.elseContentBlock
{{/child}}
```

You can use it to let your `child` template choose what it is going to render based on some context, as shown in the example [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers).

It was not directly pointed out in your question, but another thing to keep in mind is if you use the block syntax `{{#child}}`, then the block's content has access to your `parent` template's helpers and does not have access to the helpers of `child` template.

Comment: "the block's content has access to your parent template's helpers and does not have access to the helpers of child template" — I'm not seeing this. I've added new HTML and JS to my question to test: I'm seeing "Child extras" being created by the child helper.